# OnClose is not functioning

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have used Onclose function inside a Javascript Function when calling the function through JSP page it is not working

```
<html:text styleId="fromDate${rowCount}" styleClass="soa_chargesinput"  name="confDatalist" maxlength="12" onclick="singleDatePickerAdder(${rowCount})" readonly="true"  property="fromDate" /> in jsp i called singleDatePickerAdder function 

function singleDatePickerAdder(input){

    var todayDate = new Date();
    var monthPart = todayDate.getMonth();
    var datePart = todayDate.getDate();
    if (monthPart == 12) {
        monthPart = monthPart-1;
    }
    var twoDigitMonth = (monthPart < 9)? '0'+(monthPart+1) : (monthPart+1);  
    var twoDigitDay = (datePart < 10)? '0'+datePart : datePart;  
    var currentDate = twoDigitDay + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + todayDate.getFullYear();
    $('#fromDate'+input).datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
        defaultDate: currentDate, 
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        autoclose: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,  
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var scheduleType = document.getElementById("scheduleType"+input).value;
        if(scheduleType == 1){
        document.getElementById("toDate"+input).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("toDate"+input).value = document.getElementById("fromDate"+input).value
        }
        }
    });
```

here onclose function is not working  while adding a new row it is working

when scheduletype is 1 to date should be from date but it is not changing 
while adding a new row it is getting called correctly

Comment: It's seems that the JS code doesn't set in a proper `<script>` tag. I'm guessing that this code is partially, - could you please try to clarify it?

Comment: Did you tried to debug this section? does the breakpoint reached the `onClose` function? Got any error on the `dev-tools` you can share with us?